# my states are empty arrays in the first render, blank page after login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, httprequest

In my React Ionic project which runs on Android, I want to be able to login and to check if I as a user have agreed with our terms of use. To do so, I have written the following function which includes:

- POST request to `'/login'` API endpoint (first Request)
- GET request to `'/terms-of-use'` endpoint
- GET request to `'/accepted-terms-of-use'`endpoint, using the token from `response.data.token` of first Request in the header
- compare `'/terms-of-use'` with `'/accepted-terms-of-use'` and render in 'TermsOfUse.tsx' what the user has still not accepted through `missingTermsofUse` array.

**If `missingTermsofUse` array has length `0`, it means that the user has already accepted all terms of use and we push him to `homePage`, otherwise we push him to `TermsOfUse` page.**

I'm using Context in order to use props everywhere in the app

**Login.tsx**

```
const history = useHistory();

  const {
    termsofUse, 
        setTermsofUse,
        acceptedTermsofUse, 
        setAcceptedTermsofUse,
       missingTermsofUse, 
       setMissingTermsofUse
  } = React.useContext(MyContext);

    const doLogin = async (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        const loginData = {
          email: email,
          password: password,
        };
    
        // plugin: https://github.com/capacitor-community/http
        const options = {
          url: "https://xxx/login",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          data: loginData,
        };
       
    
        await Http.request({
          ...options,
          method: "POST",
        })
          .then((response: any) => {
            if (response.status == 201) {
              if (response.data.token) {
                localStorage.setItem("user",   JSON.stringify(response.data));
                const options1 = {
                  url: "https://xxx/terms-of-use",
                  headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                  },
                };
                const options2 = {
                  url: "https://xxx/accepted-terms-of-use",
                  headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Token: response.data.token,
                  },
                };
                Http.request({ ...options1, method: "GET" }).then(
                  (response1: any) => {
                    setTermsofUse(response1.data);
    
                    Http.request({ ...options2, method: "GET" }).then(
                      (response2: any) => {
                        setAcceptedTermsofUse(response2.data);

    //find terms of use which user has not accepted (entries which are present in response1 but not present in response2)

                        setMissingTermsofUse(
                          termsofUse.filter(
                            ({
                              id,
                              name,
                            }: {
                              id: number;
                              name: number;
                            }) =>
                              !acceptedTermsofUse.find(
                                (entry: any) =>
                                  entry.id == id && entry.name == name
                              )
                          )
                        );
                      }
                    );
                  }
                );
   
              }
    
    missingTermsofUse.length != 0 ? history.push("/termsOfUse") : history.push("/homePage");
            }
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error:" + JSON.stringify(error));
          });
      };
```

**After Login, I get a blank page**, neither `TermsofUse` page, nor `homePage`.
Do you have any idea what might be causing the error? I think that the first render contains `null` values but I don't really know how to re write the requests in order to avoid this case (if this is causing the issue).

I'm new at React and any help would be really appreciated.

**EDIT:**

from the logs, I can see that `termsofUse`, `acceptedTermsofUse` and `missingTermsofUse` are empty. This means that during login, their initial value set in Context.tsx is rendered.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Deep inside your promise chain, you make a call to `setMissingTermsofUse`. If I understand correctly, that call seems to assume that `termsofUse`'s value has been updated (due to the call to `setTermsofUse` earlier on). However, calls to set state are asynchronous, so your code can't rely on them happening immediately. My guess is that your `doLogin` function is closing over a stale value of `termsOfUse` (probably the empty array you initialise it as) -- and then filtering that empty array, which naturally will only give you back an empty array.

Comment: yes, this is what I have understood too. But how to avoid the empty arrays for termsofUse & acceptedTermsofUse? How to avoid their initial render?

Answer (score 1):

I am not very knowledgeable about React, but I found a couple of potential issues related to how asynchronous code is handled:

1. You are using await and .then() at the same time

```js
await Http.request({
      ...options,
      method: "POST",
    })
      .then((response: any) => {
...
```

I would recommend sticking to only one method of handling promises. You can find plenty of info on async/await vs then/catch on google, here's one of the results that I thought was well explained (not mine): https://medium.com/@dio.hamidou/async-await-vs-then-catch-4f64d42e6392

2. The line

```js
acceptedTermsofUse.length != 0 ? history.push("/termsOfUse") : history.push("/homePage");
```

will be executed before you get the answer from both GET '/terms-of-use' and '/accepted-terms-of-use', as it is not inside the inner most .then(). This might be the reason you are getting an empty **missingTermsofUse**

Hope this helps debug further your issue!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I took it in consideration and made the proper changes. As far as I have understood, I get a blank page because the first render returns empty arrays for termsofUse and acceptedTermsofUse and therefore, empty missingTermsofUse too. I'm trying to figure out how to avoid first render :/

Answer (score 1):

Deep inside your promise chain, you make a call to `setMissingTermsofUse`. If I understand correctly, that call seems to assume that `termsofUse`'s value has been updated (due to the call to `setTermsofUse` earlier on). However, in React, calls to set state are asynchronous, so your code can't rely on them happening immediately. My guess is that your `doLogin` function is closing over a stale value of `termsOfUse` (probably the empty array you initialise it as) -- and then filtering that empty array, which naturally will only give you back an empty array.

I think you'd either need to move the logic responsible for figuring out the "missing terms of use" inside an effect (using the `useEffect` React hook) and then have the effect only activate when `termsofUse` and `acceptedTermsofUse` are updated. The code inside the effect will have access to the updated values (since React runs effects after changes in state have occurred).

Alternatively, you already have access to the newer values for `termsofUse` and `acceptedTermsofUse` within your `doLogin` function (from the requests you've sent). So maybe just use those responses' data directly to figure out the missing terms of use.

Untested, but something like:

```
const doLogin = async (e: any) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const loginData = {
    dateOfBirth: birthday,
    postalCode: postalCode,
  };

  // plugin: https://github.com/capacitor-community/http
  const loginResponse = await Http.request({
    url: "https://xxx/login",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data: loginData,
    method: "POST",
  });

  if (201 !== loginResponse.status || !loginResponse.data.token) {
    return console.log(
      "Response status indicates resource may not have been created or no token was included in response.",
      { response: loginResponse }
    );
  }

  localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(loginResponse.data));

  const token = loginResponse.data.token;

  const termsOfUseResponse = await Http.request({
    url: "https://xxx/terms-of-use",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    method: "GET",
  });
  setTermsofUse(termsOfUseResponse.data);

  const acceptedTermsOfUseResponse = await Http.request({
    url: "https://xxx/accepted-terms-of-use",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Token: token,
    },
  });
  setAcceptedTermsofUse(acceptedTermsOfUseResponse.data);

  const missingTermsOfUse = termsOfUseResponse.data.filter(
    ({ id, name }: { id: number; name: number }) =>
      !acceptedTermsOfUseResponse.data.some(
        (entry: any) => entry.id == id && entry.name == name
      )
  );
  setMissingTermsofUse(missingTermsOfUse);

  missingTermsOfUse.length !== 0
    ? history.push("/termsOfUse")
    : history.push("/homePage");
};
```

---

The main changes made are:

- Flattened your nested promise chain and asynchronous logic, so hopefully it's more readable although

  - it's missing some error handling
  - if you're setting state after some asynchronous operation (i.e. the HTTP request here), the advice I've seen is that you should first check if the component is still mounted before proceeding to set state.
- Used the `some` array method (instead of `find`) when filtering the missing terms of use, since you're only interested in a boolean.
- Used the data from the responses to both: set the new state and figure out the missing terms of use.
- The routing/pushing logic is now dependent on `missingTermsOfUse` (your code was using `acceptedTermsofUse`, which seemed to contradict this part of your question):

> If **missingTermsofUse** array has length 0, it means that the user has already accepted all terms of use and we push him to homePage, otherwise we push him to TermsOfUse page.

---

Side note: You appear to be using TypeScript. If so, it's generally recommend to avoid using `any`, since you're opting out of the main benefits and safety that TypeScript provides.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort! I implemented my function based on your notes but `actualTermsofUse` and `acceptedTermsofUse` are still empty, so their initial value is rendered. Therefore, `missingTermsofUse` is empty too and I still get a blank page. Regarding useEffect(), I don't know how to use it because the request `/accepted-terms-of-use` should use the token of `/login` response in its header. And we can get the token only after submitting the button behind of which, we execute `doLogin()`.

Comment: Can you share these three parts of your code: #1 how you're creating the context (somewhere in your code, there should be a `React.createContext` call), #2 how you're providing that context within your application (somewhere there should be a `context.Provider value={/* some context expression here here */}`), #3 how you're consuming that context (somewhere there should be a `useContext(context)`). This should rule out any issues relating to creating, providing and consuming the context.

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with Context, because other parts of the app work properly. The app crashes now that I'm trying to check if the user has accepted terms of use. If I remove this part and do a simple login, everything is ok.

Comment: Yes, the context seems to be handled correctly. I've not used Ionic framework before or `IonicReactRouter`, but something also worth checking is whether your routes are all correct. For example,  your `Route` has a `path` prop of `"/login-with-birthday"`, but the default redirect is to `"/login"`. Do they need to be the same? Also, the `Login` component will attempt to redirect to `"/termsOfUse"` path, but there doesn't seem to be any `Route` containing `path="/termsOfUse"`.  Just before you call `history.push` (in `doLogin`), I would log what `missingTermsOfUse` is and the route being chosen.

Comment: yes, it was a mistake while editing the question here. I have lots of routes in my app and I had copied the wrong one. I edited it. I added /termsOfUse in the question too, had forgotten to copy it here. I have logged `missingTermsOfUse` and it is an empty array. Since it is an empty array, I suppose to redirect us to '/homePage' but this doesn't happen either.